# setContentView gives an exception

Tags: android, exception, focus, state

In my android app I set

this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
Then my touch screen event doesnt’ work any more.

Further Explaining,

I have a button and onClick it changes the contentView by setContentView(R.layout.choose_player);.
It works fine. But if you take the focus to the button by the trackball(making it yellow) and tap on it, it gives the exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
  this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);         
  setContentView(R.layout.main1);    
} 

public void onClick(View v) {    
  setContentView(R.layout.main2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use setContentView only once in your 'onCreate' method, in general for the main window (one Activity = 1 view)

in your case you should probably change your Background..

Answer (score 2):

i cant understand properly first. I think you may be using setContentView method multiple times. one is to set the layout on the view. another one inside the click event. right? that not works. use that method once to set the layout. on click event you have to do your tasks on the views inside the layout. hope it helps. please post some code snippets for the perfect answers.