# Android full Screen flag gives an exception

Tags: android, fullscreen, state

In my android app I set

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
```

Then my touch screen event doesnt’ work any more.

Further Explaining,
I have a button and onClick it changes the contentView by `setContentView(R.layout.choose_player);`. It works fine. But if you take the focus to the button by the trackball(making it yellow) and tap on it, it gives the exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view

Comment: possible duplicate of [setContentView gives an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863015/setcontentview-gives-an-exception)

Comment: This is the same as your previous question.  If you have more information to add please edit your original question rather than asking the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

just remove "this" from your call. Then it would look like as below...
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);